# ¿Hay un constructor por defecto sin variable que se necesiten redefinir las clases hijas en C++?

Tags: c++, herencia, constructor

Al compilar un programa, tengo una curiosa error :

```
MaxSize.cpp: In constructor ‘MaxSize::MaxSize(int)’:
MaxSize.cpp:7:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘TasMin::TasMin()’
 MaxSize::MaxSize(int size){
In file included from MaxSize.h:1:0,
                 from MaxSize.cpp:3:
```

Pensaba que fuera porque falta una redefinición de un construcor en `MaxSize.h` que hereda de `TasMin` pero no tiene `TasMin.h` un constructor `TasMin()`, solo `TasMin(int size)` :

```
class TasMin
{
  public:
    TasMin(int size);
    // eso es...
```

Comment: @gbianchi digame ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++, por defecto, tiende a crear una implementación base de ciertas funciones básicas, que son:

- Constructor por defecto
- Constructor copia
- Constructor *move* (C++11)
- Destructor
- Operador de asignación
- Operador de asignación *move* (C++11)

El problema surje cuando se proporcionan funciones específicas. En tal caso el compilador deja de implementar determinadas funciones.

Por otro lado, cuando heredas una clase la clase base siempre ha de llamar a algun constructor de la clase padre. Si no se especifica ningun constructor el que acaba siendo llamado es el constructor por defecto como se ve en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
struct Base
{
  Base()
  { std::cout << "Base::Base()\n"; }
}

struct Derivada : Base
{
  Derivada()
  { std::cout << "Derivada::Derivada()\n"; }
}

int main()
{
  Derivada d;
}
```

Salida:

```
Base::Base()
Derivada::Derivada()
```

En tu caso, al implementar un constructor específico el compilador deja de lado la implementación implícita del constructor por defecto. La solución es implementarlo explícitamente o llamar a un constructor base diferente:

Implementación explícita

```
class TasMin
{
  public:
    TasMin(){ } // Constructor por defecto explicito
    TasMin() = default; // Constructor por defecto (C++11)
    TasMin(int size);
};
```

Llamar a un constructor base explícito:

```
MaxSize::MaxSize(int size)
 : TasMin(size)
{ }
```

Comment: ¡ Muchas gracias, eso esta muy claro !

Answer (score 1):

Cuando creas una instancia de una subclase, [lo que se hace es](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/114-constructors-and-initialization-of-derived-classes/):

- Se reserva la memoria necesaria.
- Se llama al constructor de tu clase derivada.
- **Se llama al constructor apropiado de la clase padre**.
- Se procesa la lista de inicialización.
- Se ejecuta tu constructor.
- Se devuelve el objeto.

Y ¿cuál es el constructor apropiado de la clase padre? Si sólo tienes una clase padre y un constructor por defecto (sin parámetros), pues ése. Si no, tendrás que especificar tú el constructor al que se llama; por ejemplo

```
class MaxSize: public TasMin
{
   public:

      MaxSize(int size) : TasMin(size) {
         ...
      }
   ...
 }
```

Comment: Ya te iba a preguntar por qué habías borrado la pregunta...

Comment: @eferion la tuya está más actualizada e incluye la cuestión de las funciones por defecto; la verdad que si incluyes el punto de que el constructor de la subclase ha de llamar a un constructor de la superclase queda perfecta y borro ésta.

Comment: Aun así no tengo pensado incluir lo que has puesto sobre las operaciones a realizar en el momento de construir un objeto. Yo dejaba viva esta respuesta